# How to add Back, Previous and Next buttons to detail record page of an object using visualforce page

Tags: apex, visualforce, controller

I want to display some contacts in table and if i click on any one record on table it's redirect to details page. To get this i developed the following controller and visual force page.

controller:

```
public class paginationController {
    public List<Contact> cons {set;get;}
    public List<Account> accs {set;get;}

    public paginationController (){
        cons = [select LastName,Email from contact];
        accs = [select Name,phone from Account];
    }
}
```

Visualforce page:

```
<apex:page controller="paginationController" sidebar="false" showHeader="false">
    <apex:pageBlock id="one" >
        <apex:pageBlockSection >
            <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!cons}" var="a" >
                <apex:column >
                    <apex:outputLink onclick="window.open('/{!a.id}')"  id="theLink">{!a.LastName}</apex:outputLink>
                </apex:column>
                <apex:column value="{!a.Email}"/>
            </apex:pageBlockTable>
        </apex:pageBlockSection>
    </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:page>
```

Later, in the detail page of a every record i need to add back, previous and next button. As the buttons says if user click on next button then page display the next contact record, like wise if user click on previous button then page display the previous contact record and also if user click on back button then page needs to redirects to previous link(which means previous page). I am completely unable to get this requirement.

could any one please help to get out of this issue...!

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Currently you are navigating to standard detail page, instead you may want to use custom page to display detail records. Better suggested to display records in popup/modal dialog.

Comment: Yes Rahul Sharma, even you can also provide for custom page.